# Display image after capturing in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been trying to make an application that invokes camera through page rendering. I have used Custom Renderer from Xamarin. My problem is I need to send the picture to the other page/activity in the "Native" after clicking, but currently it is saving the picture in the gallery of the device.

For example: I click the image and then the image gets displayed with the message "Do you want to save it?". This has to be done in native rather than PCL. I have been trying through intent but that doesn't work.

All my code right now doing is saving the image to the gallery.

```
try
 {

    var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
    var folderPath = absolutePath + "/Camera";
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("photo_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
    image.Recycle();

    // imageByte = ((byte[])image);

    var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);

    var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
    intent.SetData(uri);
    //intent.PutExtra("image", imageByte);

    MainActivity.Instances.SendBroadcast(intent);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Passing bitmap through intent. 
Activity 1:

```
byte[] imageByte;
        var image = textureView.Bitmap;
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
       // ByteArrayOutputStream _bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, memStream);

        imageByte = memStream.ToArray();
        Intent i = new Intent(this.Context, typeof(CameraDisplay));

        i.PutExtra("image", imageByte);
        activity.StartActivity(i);
```

Activity 2:

```
byte[] Image = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("image");
```

imageView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView1);

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Image, 0, Image.Length);

      imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```